# How to extract data from two table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract data from two tables. I have a table `User` with the columns  `User_id`, `UserName` and `UserLoginName`.

The other table is `UserContactDetail`, with the columns `Contact_id`, `Contact_detail_type`, `Contact_detail` and `User_id` (foreign key.)

Contact detail type are like this:

```
1 = address
2 = city
3 = phone number
```

Now I want all users with their contact detail of type 3.
For example: if data in Contact detail is

```
user_id - COntact_detail_type - contact_detal

12     -     2               -    ABC
12     -     3               -  95412545
```

If user contact detail type is 3 is exist then selected contact detail and if not then it should be null. How can I do this?

I have tried this but there are 200 users it select only those which are in contact detail table.

```
SELECT [User].[user_name],[User].[user_id],
       [UserContactDetail].[contact_type_id],
       [UserContactDetail].[contact_detail]
FROM [UserContactDetail]
  INNER JOIN [User] ON [UserContactDetail].[user_id] = [User].[user_id]
where [UserContactDetail].[contact_type_id] = 2;
```

Comment: Why have you tagged both `mysql` and `oracle`? What **RDBMS** are you using?

Comment: what you have tried so far and post your question in more meaningful way

Comment: I am using sql server. I need query thats why

Comment: @hiba You want to select for id = 3 and in where clause you have mentioned 2???

Comment: I got the answer by mukesh kalgude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
select * from User as a
Left join ContactDetails as b 
On  a.user_id=b.user_id 
and b.Contact_detail_type=3
```